# Как в документе XML удалить последнюю запись

Tags: c#, xml

Всем здравствуйте, есть у меня метод, он создает xml, теперь у меня задача, удалить последнюю запись в документе. Как это можно сделать,
вот код метода, который создает документ.

```
   public void getXML(string[] mass )
        {
            // имя файла с заказами,лежит в папке с сервером
            const string NAME_FILE = "Zakaz.xml";


            // елси файл существует
            if (File.Exists(NAME_FILE))
           {

               // тогда дописываем заказ к уже имеющимся
               XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(NAME_FILE);
                doc1.Root.Add(new XElement("Заказ",
                   new XElement("date", mass[0]),
                   new XElement("Имя", mass[1]),
                   new XElement("Выбранное-время", mass[2]),
                   new XElement("Количество", mass[3]),
                   new XElement("Выбранный-товар", mass[4]),
                   new XElement("Доставка", mass[5])));

               doc1.Save(NAME_FILE);

           }
           else
           {
                // елси файла нет ,создаем его
               XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Заказы"));

               doc.Root.Add(new XElement("Заказ",
                   new XElement("date", mass[0]),
                   new XElement("Имя", mass[1]),
                   new XElement("Выбранное-время", mass[2]),
                   new XElement("Количество", mass[3]),
                   new XElement("Выбранный-товар", mass[4]),
                   new XElement("Доставка", mass[5])));

               doc.Save(NAME_FILE);

           }

            // Увеличиваем счетчик успешных заказаов, по нему отсчитываем количество успешных заказаов.
            // Логика такая, если запись произошла, значит заказ состоялся, и тогда счетчик увеличивается.
           Interlocked.Increment(ref callCount);

        }
```

Вот XML на выходе.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Заказы>
  <Заказ>
    <date>09.09.2018 19:06:25</date>
    <Имя>Иван Иванов</Имя>
    <Выбранное-время>9/9/2018 12:00:00 AM</Выбранное-время>
    <Количество>87</Количество>
    <Выбранный-товар>Война и мир</Выбранный-товар>
    <Доставка>DHL</Доставка>
  </Заказ>
  <Заказ>
    <date>09.09.2018 19:07:03</date>
    <Имя>Иван Иванов</Имя>
    <Выбранное-время>9/16/2018 12:00:00 AM</Выбранное-время>
    <Количество>875</Количество>
    <Выбранный-товар>Война и мир</Выбранный-товар>
    <Доставка>Почта России</Доставка>
  </Заказ>
  <Заказ>
    <date>09.09.2018 19:07:42</date>
    <Имя>Иван Иванов</Имя>
    <Выбранное-время>9/16/2018 12:00:00 AM</Выбранное-время>
    <Количество>875</Количество>
    <Выбранный-товар>Унесенные ветром</Выбранный-товар>
    <Доставка>Самовывоз</Доставка>
  </Заказ>
 </Заказы>
```

Вопрос, как удалить такую запись. Она последняя в списке.

```
 <Заказ>
    <date>09.09.2018 19:07:42</date>
    <Имя>Иван Иванов</Имя>
    <Выбранное-время>9/16/2018 12:00:00 AM</Выбранное-время>
    <Количество>875</Количество>
    <Выбранный-товар>Унесенные ветром</Выбранный-товар>
    <Доставка>Самовывоз</Доставка>
  </Заказ>
```

Comment: .Last().Delete()

Comment: @iluxa1810 Увы не работает нет команды Delete()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
doc.Root.Elements().Last().Remove();
```

или можно так

```
doc.Root.LastNode.Remove()
```

Comment: Спасибо заработало

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что как-то так:

```
doc.Root.Descendants('Заказ').Last().Remove()
```

Comment: Увы не работает, команда Delete() отсутствует, у меня студия 13.

Comment: Remove, а не Delete

Comment: Да заменил, но не удаляет, запись остается на месте

Comment: Из-за `Descendants` это удалит последний узел `Доставка`.